How to create a fractal background similar to this one using JavaScript and WebGL/Canvas?
I'm trying to create a fractal background similar to the one shown in the image (link below). It has an interesting structure, resembling branching fractals with smooth color transitions. I've searched online and even consulted ChatGPT, but I haven't found a clear understanding of how to achieve such an effect.
Link to the image I'm aiming for

Questions:
Is it possible to create such a background using JavaScript, WebGL, or Canvas?
What algorithms or techniques can be used to generate similar fractals? For example, would fractal tree algorithms, Perlin noise, or something else be appropriate?
Is WebGL a good choice for creating this effect? If so, what are the key steps or tools to use?
Is it possible to achieve a similar effect using Canvas, or would it be better to focus on WebGL for better performance?
I've tried using Canvas to generate random fractals, and I've also explored working with WebGL. However, I encountered difficulties when trying to create complex and detailed structures like the one in the image.
My Expectations:
I'd like the background to have random variations, resembling branches, but still remain smooth and not overload the browser.
I am interested in whether there are existing libraries or examples that could help me.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or directions that could help me implement this effect. Links to code, articles, or tutorials on similar topics would be especially useful.
Thank you for your help!

Adapted from plasma effect by https://github.com/bertjan/html5-canvas-js-plasma - it's a start


function colorToRgb(color) {
  return {
    r: 255,
    g: 255 * Math.cos(color * Math.PI),
    b: 255 * Math.sin(color * Math.PI)
  };
}

function setPixel(ctx, x, y, rgb) {
  var index = (x + y * ctx.canvas.width) * 4;
  var pixels = ctx.canvasImageData.data;
  pixels[index] = Math.floor(rgb.b / 128) * 128;
  pixels[index + 1] = 0;
  pixels[index + 2] = 0;
  pixels[index + 3] = 255;
}

function calcPlasma(ctx, x, y, time) {
  var size = ctx.canvas.width / 64;
  var result = 0;

  result += Math.sin(x / size + time);
  result += Math.sin((y / size + time) / 1.8);
  result += Math.sin((x / size + y / size + time) / 2.4);

  var cx = x / size / 10 + 1 * Math.sin(time / 4);
  var cy = y / size / 10 + 1 * Math.cos(time / 3);
  result += Math.sin(Math.sqrt(100 * (cx * cx + cy * cy + 1)) + time);

  return result;
}


var t = 0.0;

function updateLoop(ctx) {
  var speed = 0.05;
  t = (t + speed);

  for (var x = 0; x < ctx.canvas.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < ctx.canvas.height; y++) {
      var color = calcPlasma(ctx, x, y, t);
      var rgb = colorToRgb(color);
      setPixel(ctx, x, y, rgb);
    }
  }

  ctx.canvasContext.putImageData(ctx.canvasImageData, 0, 0);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    updateLoop(ctx);
  });
}


function initCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = 318;
  canvas.height = 216;
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var canvasImageData = canvasContext.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var context = {
    canvas: canvas,
    canvasContext: canvasContext,
    canvasImageData: canvasImageData
  };

  return context;
}

var context = initCanvas();
updateLoop(context);
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>



